# Cloud page access cost the per year API limit

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, account, cloudpage

I would like to know whether the cloud pages accessed by the users would be considered as a get API and the per year limit of n million APIs (6M for corporate account and 200M for enterprise) would be affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Page impressions don't impact your API limits (unless you of course utilise Ampscript/SSJS within such a Cloud Page to call SFMC API).

What they DO impact, is the number of consumed Super Messages, which is a billable unit, similar to your emails. Each Cloud Page impression equals 1 Super Message.

Using Code Resources under Cloud Pages, doesn't consume additional Super Messages.